# Show that in any field holds $((x^r-1),(x^s-1)) = x^d-1 \iff d= \gcd(r,s)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that in any field holds $((x^r-1),(x^s-1)) = x^d-1 \iff d= \gcd(r,s)$.

I define $r=ad$ and $s=bd$, then we have $((x^{ad}-1),(x^{bd}-1)) = x^d-1$, but the annoying thing for me to proceed are those "$-1$".

From literature:

> For non-negative integers a and b, where a and b are not both zero,
>   provable by considering the Euclidean algorithm in base n we know
>   $\gcd(n^a − 1, n^b − 1) = n^{gcd(a,b)} − 1$.

Some hints for a proof that doesn't use the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: I can't understand this passage; if $n > m$, then

$$\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) =\color{red}{ \gcd(a^n - 1, a^n - a^{n-m}) = \gcd(a^{n-m} - 1, a^m - 1)}$$

Comment: If $d$ divide both, $d$ must divide  $a^n-a^m=a^m(a^{n-m}-1)$ But $d\nmid a^m$

Comment: In my case, your $d$ is my $x^d-1$, right? Sorry I want to understand clearly

Comment: I've stated common divisor, ultimately this leads to the greatest common divisor

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link to the other tread